# While changing limits on integral, when using substitution , both upper and lower limits comes same, does this mean the value of integral is zero?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, substitution

[image]

When i did that substitution both upper and lower bound comes out to be same, i have solved the integral  using trigonometry and ans is not zero.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: Warm welcome to MSE! The expectation we have for each other here is that we write posts in mathjax when posting questions. I suggest the link by saulspatz to read up more on that.

Comment: Ok i’ll learn it,thanks

Answer (score 1):

The formula $$\int_a^b f(g(x))\,dx=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(y)\frac1{g'(g^{-1}(y))}\,dy$$

holds under the assumption $g:(a,b)\to\Bbb R$ is differentiable and with non-zero derivative. This is not the case for $g(\theta)=\sin(2\theta)-2$ on $(0,2\pi)$. For your substitution(s) to work you have to split the integral as $$\int_0^{2\pi}=\int_0^{\pi/4}+\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}+\int_{3\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}+\int_{5\pi/4}^{7\pi/4}+\int_{7\pi/4}^{2\pi}$$

You can also, thanks to periodicity, do $$\int_0^{2\pi}=\int_{-\pi/4}^{7\pi/4}=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}+\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}+\int_{3\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}+\int_{5\pi/4}^{7\pi/4}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification